# Python command for enabling/disabling startup apps

Tags: python

I'm creating a GUI with Python and I want to add a 'Run on Startup' checkbox to my app. Only I can't find a way to enable/disable run on startup with Python, like you can in the task manager.

Because this is achievable through the task manager, there should be a command for it, no?

Comment: You should be able to do so by tempering with the Windows registry. You can edit it using the `winreg` package.